# Is there any way to draw to the screen outside of OnDraw() in MFC?

Tags: mfc, ondraw

I'm making a MIDI sequencer in MFC and I'm trying to make a scrolling playhead but while the play MIDI function is running the OnDraw function won't run simultaneously. Is there any way of making it so that they can both run simultaneously or drawing to the screen in my play midi function?

Comment: you probably want to move your midi playing to a background thread. Don't block the UI thread, there are lots of things require pumping messages, painting is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look to utilize multiple threads.  But, to answer your specific question, you can write to the screen at any time as long as you have the device context.  Having said that, I would not recommend writing outside the "normal" draw cycle.